# jquery response add html

Tags: jquery

when I post ajax data and then alert response it adds html to it

```
369<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>
...
....
```

I just want 369 from there...how would I do that..I dont want the complete html
thanks

**EDIT**
 where do I say data type here?

```
var data = {

                'data[id]'      :    $j('#Id').val(),

                };                                                           


        $j.post('/controller/update', data, function(response){  
              alert(response)

}
```

Comment: what does the page you're posting to look like

Comment: It's probably added by the CMS/framework used to deliver the pages, more info is needed...

Comment: Problem is, you are outputting your data directly in the controller and not in the view, which is probably using some default HTML template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be doing that... perhaps there is an error on the page you're making the ajax call to which is where the extra html comes from... what is the exact html that you're getting that is undesireable?

Can you post the javascript you're using to make the ajax call and the entire response you're getting back from the ajax call?

Comment: i think he is process and painting data in html file and sending it back , either he can delete all the contents..or change the response type.

Comment: there was an error in the page and hence was returning the complete html

Answer (score -1):

Make your ajax response only **Json or xml**

Don't return html file or html type. Move to either **Json or XML**

and it should work

More documentation here

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

example

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "localhost/getsomepage.aspx",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @auto , make your server response to xml , and specify to the ajax that it is getting xml back...and it should just work.

Comment: This won't control how the server should reply. This will only tell that the response is *supposed* to be of the type you ask for...

Comment: @Capsue , you have to take care of the server side response , it can respond with a json or xml or pure text...

Comment: @kobe of course but in this case the HTML output is unwanted and setting the dataType won't solve anything.

Comment: @Capsule , yeah thats right , setting the dataType is just telling the ajax a head that the response is coming back in xml , if it gets anything otherthan that it fails..that is the use of dataType there.

Comment: @Auto make suer that /controller/update returns proper data , it shouldn't output html at all.. that is the issue in your case , if you just need a number return a xml file

Answer (score -2):

Explicitly set the dataType in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'myurl.php', dataType: 'text', success: function(data) {console.log(data)} });
```

Comment: So what? If myurl.php returns HTML, it sure will be treated as text but it won't magically strip the garbage.

Comment: @capsule , as i said you can use .aspx or php or wcf or jsp to get the responses , but it the duty of back to send the right response.